# How do I manage my Skype chat and call history?

Tags: skype, history, chat

Is there a way to selectively remove some of the historic messages and calls? I'm looking to keep the history of my business calls and chat messages, but clear the private ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help:
For 30 days, Skype keeps all of your text-based chats stored in the cloud. If you’d like to keep a longer archive of your chat history, you’ll have to make manual backups.
[How to Back Up Your Skype Chat History](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/backup-skype-chat-history)

If using Windows, this will help with upgrade:
    Select Tools from the top tool bar. 
    Select Export chat history from Skype. 
    Follow the steps in the wizard.
[Is my full conversation history transferred when I upgrade?](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34850/getting-to-know-version-8-and-above-skype-for-desktop?setlang=en)
[Delete a message:](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34636/how-do-i-remove-or-delete-an-instant-message-in-skype?q=keep%20the%20history%20of%20my%20business%20calls%20and%20chat%20messages%2C%20but%20clear%20the%20private%20ones.)
[For Mac history:](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10888/how-do-i-manage-my-conversation-history-in-skype-for-mac?q=manage%20my%20conversation%20history%20in%20Skype)
To change how long you keep your Skype history on your computer:
    Select Skype > Preferences... and then select Privacy.
    Next to Save chat history, choose from the drop-down Forever, 1 year, 3 months, 1 month or Never.

Sorry for not writing more detail but the outline for the site but will try to come back and do so. Have just updated old links to relevant content.

Comment: Links provided are dead now. Answer is no longer valid.

Comment: @ darmual Thanks, sorry so long but have been busy, will look for links.